# dataFactory V2 - Wildcards

Tags: azure-data-lake, azure-data-factory

I am trying to move & decompress data from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1. 
I have a couple of files with ".tsv.gz" extension, and I want to decompress and move them to a different folder, which is in the same data lake.
I've tried to use the wildcard "*.tsv.gz" inside the connection configuration, so I can make this process at once.

Am I making some mistake?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just tested it, you should just use:

```
*.tsv.gz
```

Without ' or "

Hope this helped!

PS: also, remember to check the "Copy file recursively" when you select the dataset in the pipeline.

Comment: Glad to help! Make sure to mark it as correct answer so future users with this problem can benefit from this.